# Need to recall last scanned VBA coordinates

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

Here is where I am at.

I have everything completed excluding one part. I need to be able to recall the last coordinates of (b,c) and subtract one from it only if a certain barcode is scanned. It will also take cell j and add it to (t,n).

I would like to thank Tim Williams for helping me learn and get this far!
Below is the code I am working on. There are over 500 cases, but for simplicity I have attached two of the types of Cases. I only need the last coordinates recalled from Case "2 in x 16 ft R -1".

If anyone can help me with that I would really appreciate it.

```
`Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

Dim ws As Worksheet, v, n, t, b, c, e, f, g, h
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

v = TextBox1.Value
n = 0
t = 0
b = 0
c = 0
e = 0
f = 0
g = 0
h = 0


Select Case v

Case "2 in x 16 ft R -1": n = 9
t = 1
b = 6
c = 1
e = 11
f = 6
g = "W2 in x 16 ft R -1"
h = 40
j = 0.296


Case "15 - FT - R": f = 5
e = 11
n = -1

End Select


If n > 0 Then
    ws.Cells(t, n) = g

    'puts name in cell for throw away value if needed later,
    'has to be a way for a scanned item to recall last scanned item
    'and subtract 1 from grid coordinates (b, c).
    'only subtracts one if a certain barcode is scanned
    'For example "CWaste-1", or "CWaste-2" would select last (b,c) and   subtract 1
    'then it would add a value based on which (b,c) it selected and based on it is was -1 or -2
' So if Case "2 in x 16 ft R -1" was selected and then Case "CWaste-1", I  would want the
'VBA to subtract 1 from ["2 in x 16 ft R -1" (b,c)] and then add j to cell (t,n)
'Basically, I would like to recall last coordinates and then add j to (t,n)

ws.Cells(1, 1) = j

ws.Cells(b, c) = ws.Cells(b, c) + h
' adding different number based on case

ws.Cells(f, e) = ws.Cells(f, e) - 1
' always subtracts 1 from certain range based on case

TextBox1.Activate
TextBox1.Value = ""

ElseIf n < 0 Then
ws.Cells(f, e) = ws.Cells(f, e) + 1
' always adds 1 from certain range based on case

TextBox1.Activate
TextBox1.Value = ""

End If
End Sub`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, v, n
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    v = TextBox1.Value
    n = 0

    Select Case v
        Case "15 - FT - R": n = 5
        Case "16 - FT - R": n = 6
        'other cases here....
    End Select

    If n > 0 Then
        ws.Cells(n, 11) = ws.Cells(n, 11) + 1
        TextBox1.Activate
        TextBox1.Value = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

Second one could follow a similar pattern.

If you have a lot of similar tests like this it might be easier to put all of the values and corresponding row numbers etc in a table on a worksheet, then use Match() to test the entered value against the table and read back the parameter values.

Also: you're nesting your `If`'s a lot, when you could use `ElseIf` to handle that

**EDIT**: for your second one, here's an example of using a worksheet to hold the various parameters

"Config" sheet:

[image]

Code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, f As Range, rw As Range

    'is there a match for the textbox value on the CXonfig sheet?
    Set f = Worksheets("Config").Columns(1).Find(Trim(TextBox1.Value), _
                                       LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        'Got a match...
        Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rw = f.EntireRow
        'use the values from the Config sheet
        ws.Cells(rw.Cells(3).Value, 9) = rw.Cells(2).Value
        ws.Cells(rw.Cells(4).Value, 1) = ws.Cells(rw.Cells(4).Value, 1) + 13
        ws.Cells(rw.Cells(5).Value, 11) = ws.Cells(rw.Cells(5).Value, 11) - 1
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        TextBox1.Activate
        TextBox1.Value = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Tim. I have already consolidated the tests in a table. It actually works as needed. Is there a further way to shorten this? I have almost 500 cases and would love to shorten the ws.Cells(n, 11) portion. I would also like to shorten the Textbox1.Activate. I could probably name the textbox TB and make it TB.Activate. Same concept for the Textbox.Value

Comment: There's only a single instance of that `If n > 0` block: I'm not sure you really gain much by shortening it. Might be useful to update your question with your current code.

Comment: Tim, I am going to play with this a little later on. I assume I can add another variable for the column and add a comma after the : n = 5 to make it reference.  I really appreciate your help! I may post some code tomorrow morning if I need more help! You're the best.

Comment: Tim, I am having an error 1004, application or object undefined on the "ws.Cells(rw.Cells(3).Value, 9) = rw.Cells(2).Value" portion of the code in the second block you provided for testing.     I understand how the first block of code works, and the second. I am not sure why it is having an error. Maybe it is because the cell has data in it when it scans?

Comment: Update, it seems to error out on all the lines where data is picked and selected in the second block provided. It does work sometimes, it selects the correct cells and subtracts, ect.... But not always

Comment: Update, I figured out how to use the first block more effectively!

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty certain I have figured out how to do it all! I simply reference the old coordinates which I have place in two cells as variables. Woohoo!